# Extract a network from spatstat to graph object in igraph using R

Tags: r, sf, network, spatstat

I am looking for an efficient way to transfer a linear network (class `linnet`) from `spatstat`, e. g. `library(spatstat); data('chicago'); net <- spatstat.linnet::domain.lpp(chicago)` to a 'graph' object in `igraph`.

For an object of class `lpp`, I have some initial understanding:
from `lpp` back to `sf`'s `LINESTRING`s via `maptools`

```r
library(spatstat)
library(maptools)
library(sf)
data('chicago')
chicago_v1 <- spatstat.geom::as.psp(chicago) # psp
chicago_v2 <- maptools::as.SpatialLines.psp(chicago_v1) # sp 
chicago_v3 <- sf::st_as_sf(chicago_v2)
class(chicago_v3)
#> [1] "sf"         "data.frame"
```

Is there an elegant way to `graph` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sfnetworks to add an igraph class to a sf based spatial network.

```
library(spatstat)
library(maptools)
library(sf)
library(igraph)
library(sfnetworks)

data('chicago')
chicago <- sf::st_as_sf(maptools::as.SpatialLines.psp(
             spatstat.geom::as.psp(chicago)))
  nodes <- st_as_sf(as.data.frame(st_coordinates(chicago)), 
                   coords = c("X","Y"), agr = "constant") 
    node.names <- row.names(nodes)
 
g <- sfnetworks::as_sfnetwork(x = chicago, 
                             directed = FALSE, 
                             length_as_weight = TRUE, 
                             edges_as_lines = TRUE)
  class(g)
    plot(g)
```

If you want to stay in an sfnetwork class you have to activate which graph element you want to operate on eg., `g |> tidygraph::activate("edges")`